# How to initialize divs in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have installed a DataTable in my application and it returns back an error saying "DataTables warning: Non-table node initialisation (DIV). For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/2".

Now I understand that DataTables structure is meant to be working with < tr >< td >, but I would like to use spans and divs inside  as shown in the preview below.

Is there any way how data tables can work on this structure? Or if there's any good alternative which can do the same job?

Thanks.

```js
$('#dt').DataTable();

// COLLAPSE TABLE
$('tr[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){
$('.insert-here').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">

 <div class="table-responsive">
  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table" id="dt">
    <!-- Table Headings -->
    <thead class="table-header">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Status <span class="badge badge-danger profile-verification-noti">4</span></th>
        <th scope="col">Last Login</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <!-- Table Row 1 -->
      <tr class="table-chevron" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#AccountDetails">
        <td><a href="javascript:void(1);" class="right-angle option-tab"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></td>
        <td>[0708]</td>
        <td>Mark Jonas</td>
        <td>Guest</td>
        <td class="success">Active</td>
        <td>22/11/2018</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="fa-user-imp-text"><i class="fas fa-desktop"></i></a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="insert-here coll-bg" colspan="8">
          <!-- START OF COMPLETE ACCOUNT SETTINGS -->
          <div class="collapse" id="AccountDetails">
            <div class="col-12 pl-0 mt-3">
              <!-- START OF ACCOUNT SETTINGS -->
              <div class="col-4 pl-0 account-details-box float-left">
                <h2 class="accounts-heading">Account Settings</h2>
                <!-- Account Status -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 float-left">
                    <p>Account Status</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 pl-0 float-left ac-set">
                    <select class="form-control custom-select col-md-11">
                      <option>Active</option>
                      <option>Disabled</option>
                      <option>Deleted</option>
                      <option>Pending</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Account Manager -->
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 float-left">
                    <p>Account Manager</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-5 pl-0 float-left ac-set">
                    <select class="form-control custom-select col-md-11">
                      <option selected="selected">--</option>
                      <option>Bilal Khan</option>
                      <option>Rishabh Saxena</option>
                      <option>Abhishekh Joshi</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get, what's the problem of assignining `id="dt"` to the `<table>`?

Comment: There's no problem, but the divs are still inside the TD that was my question?

Comment: Your error is caused by initializing your DataTable within `<div>` whereas `<table>` is expected. When I append `id="dt"` to your root `<table>` node, no error thrown, regardless of whether you use child `<div>`'s or not.

Comment: Right. I understood. But that doesn't initialize the data tables. I have done the edits you've said but it still doesn't show the search, the sorting, and the pagination? Why's that?

Answer (score 0):

Search in your code maybe you have initialized dataTable twice in your code.
You shold have like this code:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {paging: false} );
```

Only one Time.